# Get top 2 distinct values for each column

Tags: sql, distinct

I need to pick the top 2 distinct values for each column in a table. The top 2 values are selected based on the date field.

```
Table A
status   id    Col1    Col2      Col3      Date
A        1     Name1   Name4     Name6     1/18/14 5:54
B        1     Name1   Name5     Name6     1/18/14 5:54
B        1     Name2   Name6     Name6     1/12/14 5:54
B        1     Name2   Name6     Name7     10/11/13 3:34
```

Result:

```
status   id    Col1    Col2      Col3
A        1     Name1   Name4     Name6
B        1     Name2   Name5     Name7
```

Comment: Which SQL are you using? For MySQL, at least, `DISTINCT` only returns distinct rows, you can't mix rows together like that.

Comment: @andrewtweber - Given that `DISTINCT` is part of the standard, it better behave that way in _all_ implementations.  To the OP - what have you tried so far in your query?  Dealing with `Col1` - `Col3` is going to be _painful_ - was this derived off a different table we can use (given the sample data you're using seems to be related).  What about `id`?  Presumably you have multiple values in that column...  And is the type of `date` some sort of timestamp?  And yes, we still need SQL vendor and version.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I didn't know there was a standard, cool.

Answer (score 0):

IF this for sql server you could try :

```
;with cte as(

select *,row_number() over(partition by status order by Date desc) as rn from table
)

select status,id,col1,col2,col3 from cte where rn=1
```

## [See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15119)